# Ubuntu 22.04 issue: second monitor frequently losing signal

Tags: nvidia, 22.04, multiple-monitors

I have encountered this issue:

My laptop has Ubuntu 22.04 running on it with NV 3060, ryzen 7945hx. The second monitor is Lenovo Y27-q30. It frequently loses its connection with my laptop after upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04. Such issue was previously observed on a NUC at also 22.04 connecting to the same monitor as the only screen. With my laptop, the monitor is connected via dp2typec converter, and has no problem with Windows 10/11 or Ubuntu 20.04. I don't know whether it is the problem of the system, the driver of the GPU, the monitor or some USB management devices.